# VMWare Fusion / DHCP with multiple static IPs

Tags: networking, ip-address, vmware-fusion, static-ip

I have MacBook Pro and VMWare Fusion installed on it. I set a static IP for my virtual machine DHCP network by adding

```
host pc1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:4A:C5:A2;
    fixed-address 172.16.166.131;
}
```

to a file /Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf.

Is it posible to have multiple static IP addresses set here? How?

Comment: Not really a programming question, but I think it will get answered on Super User.

Comment: Can I ask why you want two different addresses?  Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware you can not. The same limitation exist with statically assigned DHCP address on certain DHCP servers since they only allow the listing of a Mac Address once.

You can assign multiple IP address to the network card of the host IP address, or alternatively just add more Network Cards. It's a virtual machine so the amount of card you add shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, just add a second network card to the VM and set up a static assignment for that second MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Context: DHCP server reserved IPs

> Is it posible to have multiple static IP addresses set here? How?

No, it is not possible to use the DHCP server to assign multiple IPs for a single MAC.

Yes, it is possible to do that you want, but either with multiple network cards (physical or virtual, each has their own unique MAC) or by adding multiple IP to the same IP from the host. Not via DHCP but via the network settings of the OS which you want to have the multiple IPs on.